# Why this Horizontal Listview not Scrolling on flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, flutter-web, horizontallistview

I'd been trying to implement horizontal listview in flutter(Web).
The code works fine for android but somehow scroll gets disable on web .
Can anyone tell the error or improvement in the below code.
I wast something like youtube app's filter widget
[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Zzb.jpg)

```
    return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      Card1
                      Card2
                      Card3
                      Card4
 
                    ]),
              ),....closing brackets
```

Comment: Also this works on dartpad but not on Android Studio's chrome(web)

Comment: I think you can remove singlechildscrollview and give a try

Comment: since the parent is singlechildscrollview, its using this to scroll.. you can either disable scrollphysics for the same or remove it .

Comment: @Muhtar I tried removing the singlechildscrollview ,but then too it wont't work.
BTW thanks answering .

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69202112/12789200